# There is an error IN THE LAST SECOND LINE OF CODE with 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended". How to solve this?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Salary, 
  contributionRate AS "Individual Contribution Rate", 
  Salary*(contributionRate/100) AS "Individual Contribution", 
  Salary*(contributionRate/100))*0.5 AS "Company Contribution", 
  ((Salary*(contributionRate/100)) + ((Salary*(contributionRate/100))*0.5)) AS "Total Contribution"
FROM (
  SELECT Fname, Lname, Salary, 
    CASE
      WHEN Salary < 30000 THEN 3
      WHEN Salary< 45000 THEN 4
      ELSE 5 
    END  AS "ContributionRate"
    FROM Employee
) AS T
ORDER BY [Total Contribution] DESC, Lname DESC;
```

Comment: Do you see ho it is easier to read after it is indented properly?  It is polite to make code readable before you show it to people and ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an Extra ")" after the 100:

```
Salary*([T].[ContributionRate]/100))*0.5 AS "Company Contribution",
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what @Robert Paulsen said:

When you order, you need to order based on existing variable:

```
ORDER BY [Total Contribution] DESC
```

will not work. You need to do:

```
ORDER BY ((Salary*(contributionRate/100)) + ((Salary*(contributionRate/100))*0.5)) DESC
```

Comment: Actually, you can. WHERE and GROUP BY cannot.

Comment: Try this: SELECT  [MyAliasName] = [name] + '-' + [name] FROM    [master].[sys].[all_objects] ORDER BY [MyAliasName];